# "INSERT INTO" is not inserting data into database

Tags: php, mysql

I know that this was already asked several times before. One of them is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869513/php-insert-into-not-working But trying the solutions given to this one, doesn't work for me. So I have this home page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My First PHP Website</title>
</head>
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['user']){}
    else{header("location:index.php");}
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
?>

    <body>
        <h2>Homepage</h2>
        <p>Hello
            <?php Print "$user"?>
        </p>
        <a href="logout.php">Click Here to Logout</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form action="add.php" method="POST">
            Add more to list:
            <input type="text" name="details">
            <br> Public Post?
            <input type="checkbox" name="public[]" value="yes">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to List">
        </form>
        <h2 align="center">My List</h2>
        <table border="1px" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Details</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>Public Posts</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysqli_error());
                mysqli_select_db($connect, "first_db") or die ("Cannot Connect to Database");
                $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * from list");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    Print "<tr>";
                        Print '<td align="center">'. $row['id'] . "</td>";
                        Print '<td align="center">'. $row['details'] . "</td>";
                        Print '<td align="center">'. $row['date_posted']." - ".$row['time_posted']."</td>";
                        Print '<td align="center">'. $row['date_edited']." - ".$row['time_edited']."</td>";
                        Print '<td align="center"><a href="edit.php">edit</a> </td>';
                        Print '<td align="center"><a href="delete.php">delete</a> </td>';
                        Print '<td align="center">'. $row['public']. "</td>";
                    Print "</tr>";
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this action page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['user']){
    }
    else{
        header("location:index.php");
    }
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){   
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","first_db");
        $details = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['details']);
        $time = strftime("%X");
        $date = strftime("%B %d, %Y");
        $decision ="no";
        mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysqli_error());
        mysqli_select_db($connect,"first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database");
        foreach($_POST['public'] as $each_check)
        {
            if($each_check !=null ){
                $decision = "yes";
            }
        }
        mysqli_query ($link,"INSERT INTO list (details) VALUES ('$details')");

        header("location: home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        header("location:home.php");
    }   
?>
```

this was supposedly inserting the data entered into my database but unfortunately it won't do anything. I cannot figure out the solution for this one. I hope you guys could help me with this. Thank you in advance!

[image: table structure]

Comment: Why do you use `mysqli_connect` twice? Or no, __three__ times!

Comment: `$connect!=$link` confusion with connection variable

Comment: that was the other option that I did, but trying to remove that one wouldn't change anything, still it doesn't insert the data. into the phpmyadmin database.

Comment: What's the table list structure? is the primary key set as auto_increment?

Comment: @met.lord yes! the id is set to AI

Comment: just to add with the $connect issue.. with regards to your condition on if($_SESSION['user']).. it will always go to header() if session is empty will lead to 'too many redirect'. i understand that this is still unfinished, but it may cause you some other issues as well.

Comment: actually I was following this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/759094/Step-by-Step-PHP-Tutorials-for-Beginners-Creating I also send a message to the author regarding with my concerns but still the same. this drives me crazy

Comment: maybe you need other credentials to perform an insert/delete/update

Comment: @SnakeFoot what do you mean other credentials?

Comment: try checking the privileges of "root", or try with another user that has password authentication

Comment: all privileges are checked

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two connection variables $connect and $link. Use any one.

Also, you could try debugging.

```
mysqli_query ($link,"INSERT INTO list (details) VALUES ('".$details."')") or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: "Field 'date_posted' doesn't have a default value" --- this error came out

Comment: What's the data type of your date_posted column?

Comment: Is it your primary key? Please share your table structure.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the table structure

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$details = "'".$details."'";
mysqli_query ($link,"INSERT INTO list (details) VALUES ($details)");
```

Comment: there's no error, but still not inserting the data into the db

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{   
        // $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
        // mysqli_select_db($connect,"first_db") or die("Cannot connect to database");
```

**EDIT :**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","first_db");
$details = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['details']);
$time = strftime("%X");
$date = strftime("%B %d, %Y");
$decision ="no";

foreach($_POST['public'] as $each_check)
{
    if($each_check !=null ){
        $decision = "yes";
    }
}
mysqli_query ($link,"INSERT INTO list (details) VALUES ('".$details."')");

        header("location: home.php");
}
```

Comment: still not working :( no errors coming out but the input still doesn't insert in my database

Comment: @Richelle, please echo your query and try running in phpmyadmin, and check if it works or not

Comment: @Richelle, Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107641/discussion-between-ms-nehal-and-richelle).

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of issues with your two pages. Try to clear it a bit.

For your form page...
put on very top of your page, above the html tag:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ob_start();
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['user']){
 header("location:index.php");
exit();
}
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
```

Remove them of cource from where you have them. The first two lines will notify you for any errors on your php code.

Take note on the `!$_SESSION` part. This reads: if sessios is NOT set, do something. You don't need the else here, using this syntax.

Always `exit()` after a header redirection.

Now, for your second page (submit), i do a lot of changing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
session_start();
// check if session is set and if $_POST is there.. if any of these checks fails, redirect to index page
if( !$_SESSION['user'] || !isset($_POST) ){
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}

// db connection
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "first_db");
if (!$connect) { echo 'Connect to DB Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error(); exit(); }
mysqli_query($connect,  " SET NAMES 'utf8' ");

// check/sanitize $_POST variables
$details = '';
if (isset($_POST['details'])) { $details = $_POST['details']; }

// declare other variables defaults values
$time = strftime("%X");
$date = strftime("%B %d, %Y");
$decision = "no";

// insert data to db
$query = "INSERT INTO list (details) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $details)."') ";
$result =  mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));


// if all are ok, sent user to new page
header("location: home.php");
```

If any error occur, it will appear on your screen.

Hope this hepls you.

Comment: "Field 'date_posted' doesn't have a default value" --- this came out

Comment: @Richelle this must be from your form page. You need to define your variables, or make sure they are not empty, or set default values, or check spelling.

Comment: I deleted the other variables for now because I want to focus on how will the database get the data, but still..same error is coming out :( I don't know if this is a bug or what but I really wanted to know the solution